# 'setNativeProps' in officical RN DOC

Tags: facebook, react-native

I am learning how to direct manipulation in component.
link is:[enter link description here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/direct-manipulation.html#setnativeprops-with-touchableopacity)

```
 class MyButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.label}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <MyButton label="Press me!" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

But I'm not understand what's problem of this demo:

I think it's ok,and will not throw this exception:`Touchable child must either be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component.`

And I try to use setNativeProps directly by ref.

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>{this.props.label}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <MyButton
          ref="test"
          label="Press me!"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('---componentDidMount');
    //console.log(this.refs.test._root.setNativeProps);
    this.refs.test.setNativeProps({label: 'hello'});
  }
}
```

But I get some error message:`this.refs.test.setNativeProps({label: 'hello'});is not a function`

And the demonstration can not visited.

If anyone know this reason , please tell me , thank you.Best wishes.

Comment: And I found InputText is OK,why Text component does't work.

Comment: Finally,I suspect the reason is that when we use setNativeProps in Text,maybe it just change the value of text.But this will be not re-render page.